# MySQL behaves differently on 3 servers, same version

Tags: mysql

I've got this query running on two different fiddle sites, both set to use MySQL 5.6:

```
SELECT name, rank, position FROM(
  SELECT name, position,
  @rank:= IF(@prev = name, @rank + 1, 1) AS rank,
  @prev:= name

  FROM (SELECT * FROM drivers 
    LEFT JOIN results on drivers.id = results.driver_id 
    JOIN (SELECT @rank := 1) AS init
    ORDER BY name, results.position ASC) AS temp

) AS derived WHERE rank <= 3 ORDER BY name, rank
```

It's supposed to give the top 3 finishing positions of each driver. The query works on fiddle #1, but not on fiddle #2 or the production server, although all three of them are running on MySQL 5.6.

Is there a setting that I'm missing?

[Fiddle #1 - working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/470089/1/0)

[Fiddle #2 - not working](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oq9fV12S1GC8z6AK9uSMSd/0)

Comment: On Oracle computing something manually in the select like that would be very dangerous as the results are undefined and can depend on how the optimizer decides to run the query. I would guess that the same thing holds for MySQL and that the difference you get is because the systems generate different plans? Or even that they use the same plans but encounter data in a different order. Can't you use the built-in RANK function, or was that added later?

Comment: @ewramner Seems like the issue was not initializing `prev` properly. Unfortunately, `RANK` was added in 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT name, rank, position FROM (
    SELECT name, position,
        @rank:= IF(@prev = name, @rank + 1, 1) AS rank,
        @prev:= name
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM drivers LEFT JOIN results ON drivers.id = results.driver_id 
            JOIN (SELECT @rank := 1) AS init_rank
            JOIN (SELECT @prev := '') AS init_prev
        ORDER BY name, results.position ASC
    ) AS temp
) AS derived 
WHERE rank <= 3 
ORDER BY name, rank
```

I added the initialization for the `@prev` variable on a `JOIN` too.

**different demos:**

- [**demo on db-fiddle.com**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oq9fV12S1GC8z6AK9uSMSd/1)
- [**demo on sqlfiddle.com**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/becbd/1/0)
- [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c6f51ed11d8582dec55e6e240b74aae4)

---

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use the built-in [`RANK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) window function. So you don't need the `@prev` or `@rank` variables:

```
SELECT name, `rank`, position FROM (
    SELECT name, position, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name, position) AS `rank`
    FROM drivers LEFT JOIN results ON drivers.id = results.driver_id
) AS derived 
WHERE `rank` <= 3 
ORDER BY name, `rank`
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8351df915e13ab10aa6f5508a6ab37e)

Comment: That is excellent, thank you. Could you explain though why this works? I would expect `@prev` to be "initialized" after the first iteration, when `name` is assigned, which would yield `true` in subsequent iterations in the `IF` condition. Still it seems to be always `false`.